# Interactive Report to be populated only after Submit Button Click

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive report which should be populated only after selecting some variables present in Select Lists, and clicking on Submit button.

Since variables are getting populated from the same table through which the interactive report is being populated. Currently, the interactive report gets populated after selecting any value in select lists.

Is there any way by which data can be populated only after clicking the submit button?

Comment: Even though the button says "Submit", you don't actually have to submit the page. Have you considered just using a Dynamic Action to refresh the report instead?

Comment: Refreshing the report refreshes the selected values in many select lists, I have included in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood the problem:

- there's an interactive report; its query looks like (just for example) `select * From emp` (`emp` being Scott's sample table)
- there are several select list items on the page, e.g. `deptno` and `job`
- their sources are columns of the same `emp` table, e.g.

  ```
  select d.dname d, e.deptno r
  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  ```

  and

  ```
  select e.job d, e.job r
  from emp e
  ```
- as soon as you select department and/or job from their select lists, interactive report is refreshed and displays the result
- you do **not** want such a behavior, but

  - select deptno
  - select job
  - push the "Submit" button
  - then refresh the report

If that's so, I believe that select list items' **Page action on selection** property is set to something which is not `None`, but `Submit` or `Redirect and set value`. Solution? Set that property to **none**. It means that you'll select values, but report won't be refreshed until you submit the page, and you'll do that manually by pushing the button.

Comment: Issue with setting Select List Page action to null, is that all my select lists are dependent on each other, but not in strict parent-child relationship. I have set their page action on selection property to "Redirect and set value" so that other items' values are refreshed once I modify any item's value.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden item e.g. P1_SHOW_DATA and reference it in the report query:

```
AND :P1_SHOW_DATA = 'Y'
```

Then only set this item to 'Y' when the Submit button is clicked.

Comment: When setting the value of a hidden item to 'Y' and referencing it in the report query, nothing is getting displayed.